# DefaultMessageCodesResolver in Grails

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

When validating domainclasses in Grails, it uses the `DefaultMessageCodesResolver` from Spring to "extend" the set of i18n-keys to try and lookup. I would like to simplify this, and have therefore implemented my own `SimpleMessageCodesResolver` by extending the `MessageCodesResolver` interface.

However, I can't seem to make Grails pick up on this. I've declared it as a custom dependency injection, trying to override, what Spring normally does:

```
messageCodesResolver(SimpleMessageCodesResolver)
```

I still see the `DefaultMessageCodesResolver` when looking at the domain object... Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I belive your custom dependency injection should be:

```
defaultMessageCodesResolver(SimpleMessageCodesResolver)
```

`MessageCodesResolver` is an interface, but not spring bean as `DefaultMessageCodesResolver` instance is.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that as well, without success. Any other ideas? The problem evolves when validating constraints, then the DefaultMessageCodesResolver prepends a whole lot of autogenerated keys. I want to get rid of these.